# ios - foursquare access token didn't come

Tags: ios

I'm following foursquare authen guideline but I still have a problem

this is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *clientID = @"XXX";
    NSString *redirectURI = @"http://www.example.com";
    NSString *authenticateURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=%@&response_type=token&redirect_uri=%@", clientID, redirectURI];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:authenticateURLString]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"itms-apps"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *URLString = [[self.webView.request URL] absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"--> %@", URLString);
    if ([URLString rangeOfString:@"access_token="].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *accessToken = [[URLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] lastObject];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

but output from NSLog is only http://www.example.com. It has no access token return. Am i do anything wrong?

I'm open this link in Desktop Google Chrome and access token is successfully return. (www.example.com#access_token=XXX)
But I'm open this link in iPhone simulator's safari and it just return the url.

Thanks for help.

@nearonline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, and the reason is the URL in webViewDidFinishLoading will not contain the access token. But the URL in shouldStartLoadWithRequest will. Therefore you should modify the code into:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if ([URLString rangeOfString:@"access_token="].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *accessToken = [[URLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] lastObject];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

}
```